# Move the custom outlook addins to the left hand side

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add-in for Outlook using Office JS and wondering if there is any way we can position the add-in at the start of the ribbon in Outlook desktop clients rather than the extreme end? Currently all the add-ins are added at the tail end of the ribbon.

Is there any property like index which will move the add-in to the start of the ribbon ? I have searched for this in the documentation and nothing was specified related to this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not chance to do that in Office JS add-ins, it is possible only when you developing COM add-in for Outlook.

Comment: This is a correct answer. However, you can write your manifest so that it puts your buttons in a new tab, if that helps. (but you can't do what the OP is asking)